# would like to get JSONP result into JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I got some problem in JSONP result can somebody give me the idea how to reformat the JSONP .responseText result into correct JSON format.

```javascript
var result = ''
$.fn.ajaxUse = function(fullurl){
    result = $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: 'id=test',
      jsonp: 'callback_jsonp',
      url: fullurl,
      success: function(data){},
      error: function(xhr){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      },
      async: false
    }).responseText;
}

$.fn.ajaxUse(ajaxurl+'menu.php');
alert(result);
```

When I use the above code and try to return JSON result I got the result as follow. Can somebody answer me how can I parse the result in JSON format, I use `parseJSON` already and not working. I would like to remove `jQuery17018127539248006552_1322568664691` from following result and would like to get correct JSON only.

```
jQuery17018127539248006552_1322568664691({"lang":{"1":"Organization Information","2":"Project List","3":"Project Details","4":"Advanced Search","5":"Layers List"}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `result` is getting set to the return value of your `ajaxUse` function rather than the JSON that gets returned from your URL. Try -

```
var result = '';
$.fn.ajaxUse = function(fullurl){
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: 'id=test',
      jsonp: 'callback_jsonp',
      url: fullurl,
      success: function(data){
        result = data;
      },
      error: function(xhr){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      },
      async: false
    }).responseText;
}

$.fn.ajaxUse(ajaxurl+'menu.php');
alert(result);
alert(result.lang[1]);
```

Comment: This answer save me a lot of time :)

Comment: Really great idea I like your answer very much.